# Two new flags I think we could use

Tags: feature-request

I think we could use two new flags to indicate common types of problem questions:

1) Is a duplicate of ... (with a blank for a link to another question)

2) Is derivative of .... (with a place for a link to the general class of question/wiki entry covering this question).

Of course, I don't really know what the stackexchange platform supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Flag menu]

[image: Down Arrow]

[image: Close / Doesn't Belong Here Sub-Menu]

Problem solved.

The "generic" flag won't happen - the purpose of closing as a duplicate is still to *help* people but *without* wasting our community's time and patience - and that means actually going out and finding the duplicate so the OP still gets a useful answer.

Comment: Note that the second dialog box looks slightly different for users < 3k rep, but the reasons and workflow are exactly the same.

Comment: In particular, the header at top says *why doesn't it belong here* instead of *why should it be closed*

Comment: I'll point out that "It doesn't belong here" --> Duplicate is not exactly an intuitive connection.  Thanks for letting me know where it is, though.